# Can Visual Studio Code incrementally compile a Java web app project?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, war, incremental-build

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. I'm trying to use it with an existing Java web app project that uses Maven. I've downloaded the recommended Java extensions like *Java Extension Pack*, *Maven for Java*, and *Tomcat for Java*.

In IntelliJ (my usual IDE), I can go from a small Java edit to refreshed WAR in Tomcat, pretty quickly. If I edit a file and recompile the project, it only works on a few class files, and then updates an exploded WAR directory. Then you have an option with Tomcat to restart, redeploy, or simply reload resources (like JSPs). This process means that for most changes I don't have to wait long to see the results in Tomcat and my browser.

In contrast, all I know how to do in VS Code is run a maven command to package a WAR. It takes too long. Is there something like the IntelliJ process above, where it can use the Maven pom.xml for library info but do incremental/update builds and put the classes in the exploded war?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/77n6qa/jrebel_rant_alternatives/?sort=confidence

Answer (score 0):

Edit : nota solution :

From https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/77n6qa/jrebel_rant_alternatives/?sort=confidence

DCEVM and HotswapAgent

- http://dcevm.github.io/
- http://hotswapagent.org/

> I'm not sure how this compares to JRebel as we've never had the budget
>   for such software, but for free, I was very impressed.

Comment: This looks like it's beyond what I need. I'd like to reproduce the basic IDE behavior first: compile some .java to .class (without re-compiling *all* the .java files) and tell Tomcat to redeploy.